# New with VBA :)

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help with a VBA code that I made a few days ago and that I don't manage to make it work.
To sum up, I have an "export.prn" file from which I need to extract data to copy it into a row into another Excel file in a specific sheet.
When my data is in a row, I have to copy this row and transpose it into a column in another sheet. 
Then, on this column (the last one), I need to apply a formula ONLY to the cells that are not blank (except for the ones that say "Uncalib") so that the new value replaces the old one.
Then, for each cell with a formula (the non-blank ones), I need to display its absolute value in the cell to the right (for ex: C1=-21; D1=21).
Finally, for the last column (with the absolute values), I have to apply a conditional formatting rule.
So, in the end, I have 2 columns (non-absolute and absolute with CF) and the cells which were blank at the beginning will still be blank at the end.
Also, every time I run this code, the data needs to be in the next row/column so that it doesn't delete the previous data (so 1 row in the Sheet1 and 2 columns in the Sheet2 will be created for each run)

I'm very new at VBA and tried to make something but it doesn't seem to work properly especially with the line at the end : 
`If WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol).Value = "" Then`
and I don't know why (since I have a limited knowledge with this kind of stuff^^).
My code is probably too long for what I'm trying to do but I don't manage to make it shorter :/

Thanks :)

`````
Sub TM()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Réponse = MsgBox("Voulez vous importer les données ?", vbYesNo)
    If Réponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim l As Long


Dim WsCartes As Worksheet
Dim WsDonnées As Worksheet
Dim WsOrigine As Worksheet

'Set my workbooks and sheets
Set WsCartes = Workbooks("Classeur1.xlsm").Worksheets("cartes")
Set WsDonnées = Workbooks("Classeur1.xlsm").Worksheets("TM")
Set WsOrigine = Workbooks("export2.prn").Worksheets("export2")
Set WsZscore = Workbooks("Classeur1.xlsm").Worksheets("ZscoreTM")


i = 2
l = 4

WsCartes.Range("D5").Value = WsOrigine.Range("J4").Value

'Import my data from the export.prn file
While WsOrigine.Cells(l, 2).Value <> ""

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Be9*" Then

        While (WsDonnées.Range("A" & i).Value <> "")
        i = i + 1
        Wend

        WsDonnées.Range("A" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Range("J4").Value
        WsDonnées.Range("B" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("A" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        WsDonnées.Range("B" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

     If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "B11*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("C" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("C" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("C" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

        If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Al27*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("D" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("D" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("D" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Cr52*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("E" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("E" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Mn55*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("F" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("F" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("F" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Fe56*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("G" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("G" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("G" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End If


    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Co59*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("H" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("H" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("H" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Ni60*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("I" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("I" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("I" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Cu65*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("J" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("J" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("J" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Zn66*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("K" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("K" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("K" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "As75*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("L" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("L" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("L" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

     If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Mo98*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("M" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("M" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("M" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

       If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Cd114*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("N" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("N" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("N" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Sn118*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("O" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("O" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("O" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

      If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Sb121*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("P" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("P" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("P" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Ba137*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("Q" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("Q" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("Q" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Pb...*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("R" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("R" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("R" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "U238*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("S" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("S" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("S" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If

    If WsOrigine.Cells(l, 1).Value = "TM-24.4" And WsOrigine.Cells(l, 3).Value = "Se78*" Then

        WsDonnées.Range("T" & i).Value = WsOrigine.Cells(l, 7).Value

        WsDonnées.Range("T" & i).Copy
        WsDonnées.Range("T" & i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    End If


    l = l + 1
Wend

'Define the LastRow/LastCol
LastRow = WsDonnées.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = WsZscore.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = WsZscore.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Copy the last row from Sheet1 and transpose it to the last empty column in Sheet2
WsDonnées.Cells(LastRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy
WsZscore.Cells(2, LastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

'If a cell display Uncalib, display nothing
For i = 3 To LastRow2
If WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Value = "Uncalib" Then
    WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Value = ""
End If
Next i

'Apply the formula to the values expect for the blank ones
LastCol = WsZscore.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 3 To LastRow2
If WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol).Value = "" Then
    WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Value = ""
    Else
        WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=(RC[-1]-RC2)/(RC3/2)"
End If
Next i


LastCol = WsZscore.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
WsZscore.Cells(2, LastCol).EntireColumn.Copy
WsZscore.Cells(2, LastCol - 1).EntireColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
WsZscore.Cells(2, LastCol).EntireColumn.Delete


'Apply the absolute formula to the non-empty cells and display the result in the cell to the right
LastCol = WsZscore.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 3 To LastRow2
WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Formula = "=ABS(RC[-1])"
WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Value = WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Value


'Set my conditional formatting rules
Set iset = WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
'select the traffic lights iconset
With iset
    .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Symbols)
    .ReverseOrder = True
    .ShowIconOnly = True
End With
'specify amber traffic light for values >= 80% of target(2500)
With iset.IconCriteria(2)
    .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
    .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
    .Value = "=2"
End With
'specify green traffic light for values >= the target(2500)
With iset.IconCriteria(3)
    .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
    .Operator = xlGreaterEqual
    .Value = "=3"
End With

WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol).NumberFormat = "0.00"

Next i

'Display nothing and delete CF if the cell is blank
For i = 3 To LastRow2
If WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol).Value = "" Then
    WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).FormatConditions.Delete
    WsZscore.Cells(i, LastCol + 1).Value = ""

End If
Next i

WsZscore.Cells(2, LastCol).Value = WsDonnées.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value
WsZscore.Cells(2, LastCol).Font.Bold = True


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
````
`````

Comment: You can just say `WsDonnées.Range("L" & i).value=WsDonnées.Range("L" & i).value` without the pastespecial.  What is the error and where is it.

Comment: For example, when I try to run the script the first time, it works fine (1st column with values and 2nd column with CF icons). But when I run it a second time with the same values, the first column (the third one in fact^^) is filled with CF icons and not values. Another error (that happens also at the second run) is that for example the "B11*" row is empty although the first time it had a value :/

Comment: Are the CF icons being included in the lastcol definition?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the code, because they have to be displayed in the last column (the one with the absolute values). But what is strange is when is try to run it a third or fourth time, the values in the first column come back :/

Comment: I cant see the value of `lastCol`  You need to insert a break point the 2nd time and check that the `.end(xlToLeft)` is including the icon

Comment: [link](https://www.noelshack.com/2019-05-1-1548688332-photo.png)

Comment: I gave you a picture so that you can clearly see what I'm talking about :) Yeah but why does this do that only for the second run and not the third ?